# How can I get all sibling components to correctly re-render when dispatching a redux action from one sibling component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

This is basically what I am trying to accomplish using react and redux. I have a parent component which renders 4 child components. Initially the child components all display the same number, which they get from the redux store using the **useSelector** hook. Each child component can trigger a click event which will dispatch an action and change the number in the store. When you trigger the event from one child component I would like to see all 4 components render and display the new number in the store. I have, currently the following code ...

**Reducer function, to change the number (which is initialized to 1)**

```
const initialState = {
    number: 1
}
export default function numberReducer(state = initialState, action){
   
    if(action.type === CHANGE_NUMBER){
        return (
            
            {   
                number: action.payload.number
            }
        );
        
    }
    
    return state;
}
```

**The redux store**

```
const store = createStore(numberReducer);

export default store;
```

**The parent component**

```
const ParentComponent = () => {

    return ( 
    <div>
        <div><ChildComponent title="child1"/></div>
        <div><ChildComponent title="child2"/></div>
        <div><ChildComponent title="child3"/></div>
        <div><ChildComponent title="child4"/></div>
    </div> 
    );
}
 
export default ParentComponent;
```

**A given child component**

```
const ChildComponent = ({title}) => {

    console.log("Rendering " + title);
    
    const initialNumber = useSelector(state => state.number);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [newNumber, setNewNumber] = useState(initialNumber);

    const handleClick = () => {
        const action = {type: CHANGE_NUMBER, payload: {number: newNumber}};
        dispatch(action);
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {setNewNumber(e.target.value)};
    
    return ( 
        <div>
            <h2>{title}</h2> 
            <br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter number" value={newNumber} onChange={handleChange}/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={handleClick}/>
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default ChildComponent;
```

In the child component I have used the **useState** hook and the **handleChange** function to create a two way binding between newNumber and the value in the input field. Since the initialState in the store is 1, all child components start off with 1 in their respective input fields. When I then go to, for instance, child component 2, change its input from 1 to 12 and click its button, I would like all child components to render and display 12.

Since each child component has a different title prop, I can verify, using `console.log("Render " + title)`, that changing the input and clicking the corresponding button in one component, re-renders all components. However only the component that triggered the click event displays the new value of the number (from the store). The rest retain their initial value of 1.

What happens is that the store gets correctly updated. Continuing with the same example, in child component 1 (which wasen't clicked), **initialNumber** is correctly set as 12. But when initializing the component's **newNumber** variable, from the **useState** hook, its gets set to 1. Not to the new number, in the redux store. I can summarize it like this.

**Intially:**

- Child component 1 - initialNumber: 1, newNumber: 1
- Child component 2 - initialNumber: 1, newNumber: 1
- Child component 3 - initialNumber: 1, newNumber: 1
- Child component 4 - initialNumber: 1, newNumber: 1

**I go to child component 2, change its value to 12, click its button and I get**

- Child component 1 - initialNumber: 12, newNumber: 1
- Child component 2 - initialNumber: 12, newNumber: 12
- Child component 3 - initialNumber: 12, newNumber: 1
- Child component 4 - initialNumber: 12, newNumber: 1

**But I am expecting**

- Child component 1 - initialNumber: 12, newNumber: 12
- Child component 2 - initialNumber: 12, newNumber: 12
- Child component 3 - initialNumber: 12, newNumber: 12
- Child component 4 - initialNumber: 12, newNumber: 12

So the child component state, newNumber, doesn't get correctly set to the redux store number. I have attempted to directly call the setNewNumber function, and force newNumber to be set to initialNumber, but this just re-renders the component again and causes an infinite loop.

Any ideas on how I can display the updated redux store number in every child component. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now changes to the component trigger changes to redux.  But how is your component responding to changes in the redux store?  You need a `useEffect` that listens for changes  to `initialNumber` and updates the local state.  You won't have infinite loop problems so long as `initialNumber` is a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setNewNumber(initialNumber);
}, [initialNumber]);
```

That effect will solve your problems by making it so that typing in one box only changes that box until you hit "Submit".  Then all boxes will be updated to the submitted value.

I believe that this is the solution you are looking for.

---

When there is a true two-way binding such that the value in the component state is always the same as the value in the redux state then you don't really need the local state at all.

If the concept of an "unsubmitted" form state is not important to you then you can delete the local state and just use the value from redux as the value in every input.  You would dispatch to redux on every change.

```
const ChildComponent = ({ title }) => {
  
  const number = useSelector((state) => state.number);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const action = { type: CHANGE_NUMBER, payload: { number: e.target.value } };
    dispatch(action);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter number"
        value={number}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```